# How to format a yearsBetween in java?

Tags: formatting, jodatime

So I need some help formatting a display field.

```
/**
 * Creates new form birthTest
 */
public birthTest() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    wrapper = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    innerWrap = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    monthField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    dayField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    yearField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    ageField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    birthdayField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    calculate = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("test");

    jLabel1.setText("BirthDay Tester");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(85, 85, 85)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    yearField.setToolTipText("Enter a four number year");

    jLabel2.setText("M");

    jLabel3.setText("D");

    jLabel4.setText("Y");

    calculate.setText("Calculate");
    calculate.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            calculateActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel5.setText("Age");

    jLabel6.setText("Birthday");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout innerWrapLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(innerWrap);
    innerWrap.setLayout(innerWrapLayout);
    innerWrapLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        innerWrapLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, innerWrapLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(monthField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(dayField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(yearField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(11, 11, 11))
        .addGroup(innerWrapLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(innerWrapLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(birthdayField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 67, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(ageField))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(innerWrapLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(innerWrapLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(calculate))
                .addGroup(innerWrapLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    innerWrapLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        innerWrapLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, innerWrapLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(innerWrapLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(monthField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(dayField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(yearField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel4))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(innerWrapLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(ageField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(innerWrapLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(birthdayField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(calculate)
                .addComponent(jLabel6))
            .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout wrapperLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(wrapper);
    wrapper.setLayout(wrapperLayout);
    wrapperLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        wrapperLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, wrapperLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(innerWrap, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    wrapperLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        wrapperLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(wrapperLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(innerWrap, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(12, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(wrapper, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(wrapper, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void calculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    int month = Integer.parseInt(monthField.getText());
    int day = Integer.parseInt(dayField.getText());
    int year = Integer.parseInt(yearField.getText());
    String birth = monthField.getText() + "/" + dayField.getText() + "/"
                    + yearField.getText();

    DateMidnight birthdate = new DateMidnight(year, month, day);
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    Years age = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, now);


    birthdayField.setText(String.valueOf(birth));
    ageField.setText(String.valueOf(age));
}                                         

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(birthTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(birthTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(birthTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(birthTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new birthTest().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JTextField ageField;
private javax.swing.JTextField birthdayField;
private javax.swing.JButton calculate;
private javax.swing.JTextField dayField;
private javax.swing.JPanel innerWrap;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField monthField;
private javax.swing.JPanel wrapper;
private javax.swing.JTextField yearField;
// End of variables declaration
```

Here is my program, which currently runs and gives me the results I want accept for one thing.

The age output has two letters in the output. I am using the joda time libraries. I have read as much as I can find on this and can not figure out how to format the output to drop the letters. Any help would be great, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to convert `age` to a string like you did, the `Years.toString()` method 
gets called. There, the value is formatted to the ISO8601 duration format: 10 years will be displayed as P10Y.

To get the age as years, use

```
int age = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, now).getYears();
```

and display that value.